# How to bind my own Style dependency property (DP) to Button's style DP?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I've found a UserControl implementation of a virtual keyboard. There are many buttons. I want that UserControl to expose a DP "KeysStyleProperty", but how to bind it to the inner button's style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the 'LayoutRoot' DataContext of the user control to itself, you can then bind your inner buttons style to this dependency property. For more details, see this article which I wrote:

http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html

For example, is this XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl.VirtualKeyboard"
    ...>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
              x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Style="{Binding KeysStyleProperty}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And bind the LayoutRoot as follows:

```
public VirtualKeboard()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  //this.DataContext = this;
  LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've got it. There are many buttons in the UserControl. How to define a style in xaml which will be applied to the buttons and will be based (or binded to) on the DP?

Comment: Besides, DataContext is set to a ViewModel so I can't bind a style in xaml to DPs in the code-behind.

Comment: Buttons the style of which should be bind to DPs, have already binded to VMs props.